# How to run monaco editor in a browser during developing editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am sorry if my question sounds dumb but I cannot figure out how to do it. I can clone `monaco-editor-samples` and run it. But am trying to add new language. SO I've forked and cloned `monaco-languages` repository and created new folder in `src` folder. Now as I add new rules to language highlights, I want to test it in editor. How do I run editor that automatically loads my new language?

When I execute `npm run watch` I thought some localhost server would be created where I can test editor. May be does but in terminal I do not see any comment where I can access it. And I cannot find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Customs language](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages) example shows how one can register Monarch tokens directly from within Monaco (without going through the hassle of cloning `monaco-languages` and building it and so on). Does that help?